# Material components TextInputEditText margin of bottom line

Tags: android, components, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext, material-components-android

I have a problem. TextInputLayout has margin or padding with respect to the line.

I need the line to be the full width.

Docs:
https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/

[image: Screenshot of <code>TextInputLayout</code>]

Code:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputLayoutEmail"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/colorBgDisableButton"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="10dp"
    app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/text_signup_email"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorTextInput"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:errorTextAppearance="@style/ErrorTextAppearance"

    >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/inputTextEmail"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorLineInput"
        android:fontFamily="@font/century_gothic"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingStart="22dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextInput"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"

        />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: This is a known issue and the MDC-Android team is working on resolving. We'll follow up once the fix is available.

Answer (score 0):

`match_parent` both fields and all will go well